# Using LightInject (IoC) service without .svc and .config

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to create service endpoints and serviceBehaviors in code for my WCF services that are created with LightIject(IoC Container) so they has not .svc file.

Is possible to create this behaviors with code and without .config
file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do this with code. The classes you need are in the [System.ServiceModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.ServiceModel.Description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.aspx) namespaces. An example would be (this has not been tested):

```
string endPointAddress = "http://localhost:8000/MyAwesomeService"
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyAwesomeService));

var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (MyAwesomeService), new WebHttpBinding(), new Uri(endPointAddress));
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx) is a great series of MSDN articles covers WCF extensibility.